# Нет доступа к this компонента в computed свойстве

Tags: vue.js, frontend, компоненты, vuetify

Вот такой кодик:

```
    components: {Help},
    props: ['nav_elements'],
    name: "Navigations",
    computed: {
        politics_show: () => {
            this.politics_show_ = !this.politics_show_;
            return this.politics_show_;
        },
    },
    data: () => ({
        politics_show_: false
    }),
```

Использую так:

```
            <v-list-item>
                <v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-container
                        v-on:click="politics_show"
                        style="padding: 0; margin: 0"
                    >
                        <v-icon> mdi-alert-circle </v-icon>
                    </v-container>
                </v-list-item-icon>
                <v-list-item-content/>
            </v-list-item>
```

Получаю такое:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'politics_show_' of undefined"

found in

---> <Navigations> at src/components/Navigations.vue
       <VApp>
         <Courses> at src/views/Courses.vue
           <VContent>
             <App> at src/App.vue
               <Root>
```

Видимо, прикол в том, что computed вычисляется первый раз до того, как посчитается data. Обойти не получилось. Как поступают обычно?

Comment: В computed-методе Вы изменяете туже переменну, что и возвращаете. Сдается мне, у Вас есть потенциальная возможность попасть в рекурсию и забить стэк.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, вы не правы, `data` вычисляется вперед `computed`.

Ошибка говорит, что свойство `politics_show_` не может быть прочитано у `undefined`.

Ругается на `this.politics_show_`. `this` является `undefined`.

Это потому что стрелочные функции не имеют `this`, `this` берется из контекста выше (https://learn.javascript.ru/arrow-functions#u-strelochnyh-funktsiy-net-this)

Не используйте стрелочные функции в `computed`, если вам нужен доступ к экземпляру Vue

```
computed: {
    politics_show () {
        this.politics_show_ = !this.politics_show_;
        return this.politics_show_;
    },
},
```

> Не используйте стрелочные функции в свойствах экземпляра и в коллбэках, например
>
> `created: () => console.log(this.a)` или
>
> `vm.$watch('a', newVal => this.myMethod())`.
>
> Так как стрелочные функции не имеют собственного `this`, то `this` в коде будет обрабатываться как любая другая переменная и её поиск будет производиться в областях видимости выше до тех пор пока не будет найдена, часто приводя к таким ошибкам, как
>
> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined` или
>
> `Uncaught TypeError: this.myMethod is not a function`.

С сайта [ru.vuejs.org](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#%D0%A5%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B0)