# Вписать в переменную текущий роут-нейм vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как во vue.js получить имя текущего роута?

Пытаюсь получить вот так:

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'App',
        data: () => ({
            current_page: this.$route.name
        })
    }
</script>
```

но возникает ошибка:

> [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property '$route' of undefined"

Comment: Связанные вопросы: [Нет доступа к this компонента в computed свойстве](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1084107/288409), и [Потеря контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535030/288409). А еще, [искать в документации](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#data) перед тем как задавать вопрос - так же полезно, как и использовать поиск по stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В переменную (внутри экземпляра компонента) - так:

```
let currentPage = this.$route.name;
```

А в свойство компонента - вот так:

```
data() { return {
  currentPage: this.$route.name,
  // ...
}},
```

, или так:

```
data: vm => ({
  currentPage: vm.$route.name,
  // ...
}),
```

Comment: Заработало, красава!) Спасибо!